# Flux of constant vector field $F(x,y,z) = C$ is just $|C|$ times the area of the surface?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $S$ is a surface of finite area and $F(x,y,z) = C$ is a constant vector field over $S$. Is the flux over $F$ across S just $|C|$ times the area of $S$?

I'm not finding a way to argument on this. Can someone answer it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. For instance, the constant vector field $F(x, y, z) = (1,0,0) $ has flux zero through the unit square in the $xy$-plane.

The right answer is $|C| ~ A ~ (u \cdot n)$, where $A$ is the area of $S$, $n$ is the normal to your bit of surface, and $u$ is a unit vector in the directions of $C$, i.e., $u = \frac{1}{|C|} C$. (But this assumes that the surface is in fact **planar**, i.e., that the normal vector is constant over the surface!)

Because of this, a simpler formula (in the case of a planar surface piece) is that the flux is
$$
A (C \cdot n).
$$

Comment: In the general case, the normal vector is not necessarily the same in every point of the surface, so the formula you provide is not general. It is true in the case that $S$ is an affine plane (or a subset)

Comment: Ah...good point. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Project your surface $S$ to the plane perpendicular to the direction of $C$; compute the area of the projection, counting various pieces of multiple projection with signs (based on orientation of your surface $S$) and multiplicities. Multiply by $|C|$. This is the flux of $C$ through $S$.

You will get the same result using any surface with the same boundary instead of $S$ (by Stokes's theorem or by Gauss's theorem). So in a sense (which can be made precise with a bit of effort), the answer is the area "enclosed" by the projection of the boundary (times $|C|$).

This also gives a way of seeing why this is true: replace $S$ by a "cylinder" with sides parallel to $|C|$ plus a flat "cap" in a plane perpendicular to $C$. The total flux through this new surface is the same as through $S$. The flux through the sides of the cylinder is $0$ since the surface is parallel to the field, while the flux through the "base" is $|C|$ time the area of the base.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Remember that the surface integral can be calculated as follows:
$$\int_S F\text{d}\mathbf{S} = \int_S F_n\text{d}{S} = \int_S \langle F,\mathbf{n}\rangle\text{d}{S},$$
where the first term is a $\textit{field}$ integral over $S$ and the second and third terms are the $\textit{scalar}$ integral over $S$ of the normal component of the field ($F_n=\langle F,\mathbf{n}\rangle$ denotes the normal component of the field, $\mathbf{n}$ is the vector normal to the surface and has the same sense as the chosen orientation). In the general case, $\langle C,\mathbf{n}\rangle$ needn't be equal to $|C|$ (this just happens when $C$ is perpendicular to the surface in every point). In fact, if $C$ is tangent to the surface in every point (e.g., if $S$ is a plane and $C$ is parallel to the plane), then $\langle C,\mathbf{n}\rangle$ is identically $0$ and the integral is also $0$.